# Get last record in a queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

How can I retrieve the last record in a certain queryset?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

EDIT : You now have to use [`Entry.objects.latest('pub_date')`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.latest)

---

You could simply do something like this, using [`reverse()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#reverse):

```
queryset.reverse()[0]
```

Also, beware this warning from the Django documentation:

> ... note that `reverse()` should
> generally only be called on a QuerySet
> which has a defined ordering (e.g.,
> when querying against a model which
> defines a default ordering, or when
> using `order_by()`). If no such ordering
> is defined for a given `QuerySet`,
> calling `reverse()` on it has no real
> effect (the ordering was undefined
> prior to calling `reverse()`, and will
> remain undefined afterward).

Comment: as said in django docs, : "note that reverse() should generally only be called on a QuerySet which has a defined ordering (e.g., when querying against a model which defines a default ordering, or when using order_by()). If no such ordering is defined for a given QuerySet, calling reverse() on it has no real effect (the ordering was undefined prior to calling reverse(), and will remain undefined afterward)."

Comment: 2017 and the accepted answers is out of date now. As shown below you should use queryset.last().

Answer (score 171):

[Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#latest):

> **`latest(field_name=None)`** returns the latest object in the table, by date, using the field_name provided as the date field.
>
> This example returns the latest Entry in the table, according to the
> `pub_date` field:
>
> ```
> Entry.objects.latest('pub_date')
> ```

Comment: This is the neat way to do it. Also, "If your model's Meta specifies get_latest_by, you can leave off the field_name argument to latest()" as per the docs.

Answer (score 84):

The simplest way to do it is:

```
books.objects.all().last()
```

You also use this to get the first entry like so:

```
books.objects.all().first()
```

Comment: `books.objects.last() ` and `books.objects.first()` should do the trick.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer together with `XYZ.objects.first()` and  `XYZ.objects.last()`

Comment: I think Arnaud P's way is the more appropriate one. This if not mistaken will unpack all the items in DB where the later pulls the last using DB query.

Answer (score 49):

To  get First object:

```
ModelName.objects.first()
```

To get last objects:

```
ModelName.objects.last()
```

You can use filter

```
ModelName.objects.filter(name='simple').first()
```

This works for me.

Comment: What if I have added the QuerySet to a variable, how can I get the last and first then?

Answer (score 38):

Django >= 1.6

Added QuerySet methods first() and last() which are convenience methods returning the first or last object matching the filters. Returns None if there are no objects matching.

Answer (score 8):

When the queryset is already exhausted, you may do this to avoid another db hint -

```
last = queryset[len(queryset) - 1] if queryset else None
```

Don't use `try...except...`.
Django doesn't throw `IndexError` in this case.
It throws `AssertionError` or `ProgrammingError`(when you run python with -O option)

Comment: Assuming that your queryset is already ordered, this should be the "top answer",  because it's the only solution that does not hit the database again.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Model.objects.last()` or `Model.objects.first()`.
If no `ordering` is defined then the queryset is ordered based on the primary key. If you want ordering behaviour queryset then you can refer to the last two points.

If you are thinking to do this, `Model.objects.all().last()` to retrieve last and `Model.objects.all().first()` to retrieve first element in a queryset or using `filters` without a second thought. Then see some caveats below.

The important part to note here is that if you haven't included any `ordering` in your model the data can be in any order and you will have a random last or first element which was not expected.

Eg. Let's say you have a model named `Model1` which has 2 columns `id` and `item_count` with 10 rows having id 1 to 10.[There's no ordering defined]

If you fetch Model.objects.all().last() like this, You can get any element from the list of 10 elements. Yes, It is random as there is no default ordering.

So what can be done?

1. You can define `ordering` based on any field or fields on your model. It has performance issues as well, Please check that also. Ref: [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#ordering)
2. OR you can use `order_by` while fetching.
   Like this: `Model.objects.order_by('item_count').last()`

Answer (score 4):

If using django 1.6 and up, its much easier now as the new api been introduced -

```
Model.object.earliest()
```

It will give latest() with reverse direction.

p.s. - I know its old question, I posting as if going forward someone land on this question, they get to know this new feature and not end up using old method.

Comment: from docs: earliest() and latest() require either a field_name parameter or 'get_latest_by' in the model

Answer (score 1):

```
MyModel.objects.order_by('-id')[:1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use ids with your models, this is the way to go to get the latest one from a qs.

```
obj = Foo.objects.latest('id')
```

Answer (score 0):

In a Django template I had to do something like this to get it to work with a reverse queryset:

```
thread.forumpost_set.all.last
```

Hope this helps someone looking around on this topic.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

`MyModel.objects.order_by('-id')[:1]`

Answer (score -8):

The simplest way, without having to worry about the current ordering, is to convert the QuerySet to a list so that you can use Python's normal negative indexing. Like so:

```
list(User.objects.all())[-1]
```

Comment: This will query ALL objects from the DB and then will take the first one

Comment: Good point! Obviously didn't think that one through. The .reverse() answer (currently selected) is the right way to go!