# Group By Django ORM

Tags: python, mysql, django

I want to do a simple group by with django ORM.

```
SELECT * FROM user AS u JOIN user_photo AS up WHERE u.`user_id` = up.`user_id` GROUP BY up.`user_id`;
```

Structure user_photo:
id | photo | user_id

Structure user:
id | name | status | description | paid | user_id

I have another table with user photos that users upload to the database.
I can pull the informations from the user but I want only one and the last photo that the user uploaded from the user photo table.

I want to group by, by my field not using any model function like count, max, min, avg, etc

Anyone can help?

Comment: I can't use Count model function, I don't want to count anything, just group by, by my id field to skip duplicated rows from the other table

Comment: are you asking that you only want to pull the last picture submitted for each user?

Comment: I need to pull the user from one table, the other table is with the user photos uploads, I just want the last user photo from this photo table to show in a search view, got it?

Comment: kind of. try looking at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191010/get-last-record-in-a-queryset

Comment: You can use a Prefetch object, it can take a queryset. In your case Photo.objects.last() or order_by()

User.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('photos', queryset=Photo.objects.last()))

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you do a GROUP BY with .group_by(), but it's not exactly what you are looking for.

You can achieve your goal with the ORM using a prefetch_related.

The Prefetch objects allow you to do all kind of lookup using the ORM.

In your case :

```
User.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'photos',
        queryset=Photo.objects.last(),
    )
)
```

Where 'photos' is you related_name or 'photo_set' by default. Also, the .last() method can be replaced by the .order_by() of your choice.

Take note that it will differs from your SQL example in the fact that the prefetch will do an additional query instead of a JOIN.