# queryset django for last value of column if another column is equal to a value

Tags: django

I have a django video model  and i want to get the last value of "nameoriginalvideo" if owner id is equal to the current user id.

This is my mysql table equivalent to the model:
[image]
This is what i tried but it didn't work:

```
def teste(request):
    originalvideo = Videounwtm.objects.values('nameoriginalvideo').filter(owner_id = request.user.id).first().last()
    vle = originalvideo['nameoriginalvideo']
    return render(request, 'teste.html', {'vle': vle})
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which version of Django you are using?

Comment: @anuragal It's 1.11.3

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191010/get-last-record-in-a-queryset 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675672/django-get-the-latest-record-with-filter

Answer (score 0):

You can either do:

```
originalvideo =
Videounwtm.objects.values('nameoriginalvideo').filter(owner_id =
request.user.id).first()
```

or

```
originalvideo =
Videounwtm.objects.values('nameoriginalvideo').filter(owner_id =
request.user.id).last()
```

when you apply 'first()' it returns a dictionary therefore, you cannot apply 'last()' on a dictionary.

Comment: Can you show the model definition

Comment: Thank you, i posted in my answer what did make it work.

Answer (score 0):

This resolves the problem:

```
    originalvideo = Videounwtm.objects.values('nameoriginalvideo').filter(owner_id = request.user.id).order_by('-uploaded_at')[0]
    vle = originalvideo['nameoriginalvideo']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    return

last = Model.objects.filter(id= request.user.id).order_by('-id')[0]
```

This is a pseudo code.
Filter elements with user's id, Query element in reverse order of id and the 0th element will be last inserted one.